# How to insert a "data:image/png;base64,..." image into Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

For example, Janvas (online vector editor) generates previews as such links. If I insert it into address line of a browser, I get correct picture but when I try to insert it to Google Docs, it says:

```
The URL is not valid. Make sure it starts with http:// or https://.
```

Obviously I don't want save image locally first. (I don't like to think about how to name and where to save the image to local directory or look for it in loads and loads of other files, that's why I use online tool.)

Entire link. It fits into Google Doc's URL input field:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Comment: Submitted a feature request: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/drive/meet-the-community/drive-in-your-browser/desktop-other

Comment: More precise link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/drive/meet-the-community/drive-in-your-browser/desktop-other/ztrzmPHka7g

Answer (score 2):

You have a link but instead of providing an link to an image on a server, the PNG image data is in the style sheet. data:image/png;base64 tells the browser that the data is inline, is a png image and is in this case base64 encoded. Therefore it is not stored on any server. You can actually see this image without a connection to the internet. Here's some documentation on how it works https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397

Long story short you need to download the image to be able to use it anywhere. I'm sure in a not so distant future Google will add support for these but for now you'll have to sacrifice your hard drive space.

Comment: It's not related to style sheets, it's just a preview image from online graphics editor.

Comment: The problem with saving it image is not the hard disk space, but that: 1. I need to choose a name; 2. I need to find the image later to insert it; 3. It's against harmony to have additional steps involving additional entities.

Comment: It's not possible to use it without saving it locally. I was explaining how the image works and why it can not be accessed directly through google's image scraper. You're basically telling it something it's not capable of using. You'd have the same luck inputting 'c:\image.png' into the url field. Basically what you have is raw data with no server to pull an image from

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem, but it was in SVG+XML form. However, I executed [atob](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_atob.asp) against the Base64 encoded string and got:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 316 316" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0 0h316v316H0V0zm58 202v20h200v-20H58zm30 40v20h140v-20H88zM98 54v120h120V54H98z" fill="#FBFBFB" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
```

Maybe you could try a link in the HTML element after you decoded the Base64 string.